# How to completely turn off Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: security, ubuntu-12.04, buffer

I am trying to turn off Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) in Ubuntu 12.04.

What I have done is set `randomized_va_space` to 0 but still when I am looking at `/proc/<process_id>/maps` for my memory what I am getting is a randomized allocation of segments, even when I run the same program many times.

How to completely turn off ASLR in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I'm not sure of the problem.  I can try to help you troubleshoot though.

1. Are you certain that the setting took properly?  Sometimes using `sudo echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` can fail due to lack of permissions, because the sudoness is dropped when running the >.
2. Have you rebooted since applying the setting?
3. Is there a particular reason that your are disabling ASLR?  I'm sure you know that can open up quite a security vulnerability.  If you are doing exploit development or security research, you may want to switch to an older version of Ubuntu/Linux, or to a specialized distro like [DVL](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=dvl) (if you can find a copy).